# If $[K:F]$ is a prime, then $K=F(a)$ for every $a\in K - F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 28, Exercise D3.

> Prove: If $[K:F]$ is a prime, then $K=F(a)$ for every $a\in K - F$.

For every element $a\in K - F$,

1. $a$ is algebric over $F$.  Therefore $F(a)$ is a field extension of $F$.  There are only three possibilities: (i) $F(a) = K$,(ii) $F(a) \subset K$, or (iii) $K \subset F(a)$.
2. $F(a)\ne F$, as given.
3. Given $[K:F]$ is prime, there is no field properly between $F$ and $K$. 
   Hence (ii) is not possible.
4. $K\not\subset F(a)$ as $a$ is a linear combination of the basis of $K$.  So (iii) is not possible.

Hence $K=F(a)$ for every $a\in K - F$.

Is this reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do $3$ and $4$ prove that $F(a)$ must be equal to $K$? You didn't even mention that it is a subfield.

Here is a solution. $F(a)$ is by definition the smallest subfield of $K$ which contains the field $F$ and the element $a$. So $F(a)\subseteq K$. Then, by the tower law $[K:F]=[K:F(a)][F(a):F]$. Since $[K:F]=p$ is a prime number we conclude that $[F(a):F]=1$ or $[F(a):F]=p$. But this extension degree can't be $1$ because $a\in K\setminus F$, hence $F(a)\ne F$. So $[F(a):F]=p$, and hence $[K:F(a)]=1$. This means $K=F(a)$.

Comment: > "How do 3 and 4 prove that () must be equal to ?"

By (1), $F(a)$ is a field extension of $F$ so there are only three possibilities:
(i) $F(a) = K$,
(ii) $F(a) \subset K$, or
(iii) $K \subset F(a)$.

Comment: @hchar Well, it's not just because it is an extension of $F$. Note that there can be extensions which are totally different. For example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are both extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, none of them contained in the other. However, in your exercise the whole point is that by definition $F(a)$ is a subfield of $K$. So specifically here it is indeed an intermediate field between $F$ and $K$. So to prove it equals to $K$ we used the fact that $F(a)\ne F$ and that there are no "real" intermediate fields.